# Cannot create collection on Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create collection on terminal using mongo shell.
if I run

```
db_name> db.createCollection("system.indexes");
```

it outputs this error

```
MongoServerError: Invalid system namespace: db_name.system.indexes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apart from some exceptions, you don't need to create collections. When you insert any data or create an index and the collection does not exist, then it is created automatically. Which is your current database?

Answer (score 2):

Collection names cannot begin with the `system.` prefix. Please see the full list of namespace limitations.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#std-label-faq-restrictions-on-collection-names

Answer (score -2):

Create Collection using below query :

```
db.createCollection( "contacts", {
      validator: { $jsonSchema: {
      properties: {
    user_id: {
            type: "number",
            description: "must be a number and is required"
         }
      }
    }}
} )
```

Comment: I changed the name to 'system.indexes' and got the same error for the code above

Comment: can you please try this command in mongo and share output here?
command: show dbs;

Comment: @PratikPatel - the issue here is a naming issue. Also, your example adds things unrelated to the question (such as a validator and `user_id`). Also no need to run `show dbs;`.